# Exception has occurred: NoEntryPointError

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using Discord.py, and while making a command handler using COG, I got this error.

This is the main.py (main bot file)

```
# Command Handler: Import cog files.
for file in os.listdir("./cogs"): # lists all the cog files inside the cog folder.
    if file.endswith(".py"): # It gets all the cogs that ends with a ".py".
        name = file[:-3] # It gets the name of the file removing the ".py"
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}") # This loads the cog.
```

Here is the link to the only file I have in my ./cog/ directory, named "Hellgoodbye.py".

https://pastebin.com/TdE8FPxq

The error I get when I do "python .\main.py" in my VSCode terminal, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\quinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 612, in _load_from_module_spec
    setup = getattr(lib, 'setup')
AttributeError: module 'cogs.Hellogoodbye' has no attribute 'setup'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\main.py", line 141, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}") # This loads the cog.
  File "C:\Users\quinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 678, in load_extension
    self._load_from_module_spec(spec, name)
  File "C:\Users\quinn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 615, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.NoEntryPointError(key)
discord.ext.commands.errors.NoEntryPointError: Extension 'cogs.Hellogoodbye' has no 'setup' function
```

Can someone help me fix the error. i really do not know what is going on.

Comment: Your cog file needs to have a setup function

Comment: How do I add this?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you don't have `setup` function. It is necesary for an extension to load.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Name(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Name(bot))
```

This is an example of a cog file. As you can see at the very end of the code there is the `setup` function. It should be a standalone function which is not defined inside of the class.

Comment: I have exactly what you have put here, however, the only difference is that I turned "Name" (lines 4 and 8) changed to "Hellogoodbye".

Comment: So you should add the cog code do your question

Comment: I entered the link that you provided and I know the problem, you've put the `setup` function inside of the class. It should be at the and as a standalone function

Comment: I have added the cog code to my question. 
https://pastebin.com/TdE8FPxq

Comment: Modified to answer your question. It is also not a good idea to link to the code on SO, it scares people away.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

I moved

```
def setup(bot)
 bot.add_cog(Hellogoodbye(bot))
```

To the end of the file, and it is working now, besides the fact I have some other issues, but the error I asked about is fixed by this.